# Is indexing an array literal good practice?

Tags: javascript

In my code I have the following simple function:

```
function selectedWeekDay() {
    return ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'][day];
}
```

Where 'day' is an integer defined elsewhere.
This clearly works, but I actually haven't seen this type of thing done in any other code example I've seen; creating an array literal just to select from an ordered arrangement of data.

My question is, is this good practice? Or would it be better to use a switch statement?

Comment: Define this array as a constant somewhere global and pass day as argument.

Comment: Would be better as `var days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];

function selectedWeekDay(day) {
    return days[day];
}`

Comment: A switch statement is a horrible idea. Think about i18n for example.

Comment: Yes simple and clear.

Comment: Thanks guys. Don't know why I didn't just make the array global. Duh! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As such, this is perfectly fine since your array is really small. 
But with larger array it may cost you memory and/or CPU time (depending on the smartness of your Jitter and your garbage collector).

A switch statement is definitely a bad idea (it wouldn't scale for larger collections).

I would do a simple closure to improve your initial code while keeping the array private

```
var selectedWeekDay = (function() {
    var days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
    return function(day) {
        // do some bound checking
       return days[day];
    };
}());
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks!